# Windows Batch - Findstr and assign to a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to find a string in a file and assign the results to a variable for further processing. But for some reasons the code below doesn't work.

My string is always available on the 2nd line so I tried the code below, from which I can print the correct string on the console, but cannot assign it to a variable:

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%G in ('findstr /n "^" C:\myfolder\payload.xml') do if %%G equ 2  echo %%H
```

**Problem: Using the above method I'm unable to store the result in a variable**

I have tried another method as well:

```
findstr /g "FilePath" C:\myfolder\payload.xml>>D:\Data\tmp.txt
set /p "Prev_FileName="<D:\Data\tmp.txt  
echo %Prev_FileName%
```

**Problem: with this method getting the output in the file tmp.txt but not in the variable.
In both contexts used `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`**

Could you please help as I am a beginner?

Comment: Can you post a extract of your xml file, what are you searching and what you need stored into the variable?

Comment: `... do if %%G equ 2  set "var=%%H"`?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. 
My requirements are quite difficult(atleast for me). I have a XML file and in the second line there is a string(it is a file name which has to be processed). 
So I have to dynamically read it and replace it with another string which is available in a text file(this text file contains all input file names as line by line as file1.txt
file2.txt
file 3.txt). 
It would be great if you help me with an example. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are no unusual steps that need to be taken to set a variable in either context. How do you know the variable has not been set?

The first code you posted does not attempt to set anything, though if you changed the `echo %%H` into `set "Prev_FileName=%%H"`, then it should work just find.

The second code should be setting the variable.

Why do you think your variable is not being set? I suspect you are doing something like `echo %Prev_FileName%`, and not seeing your expected result. That could happen if you are within a parenthesized block of commands, since they are all parsed at once, and `%Prev_FileName%` is expanded at parse time. You say you `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`, but that does nothing unless you you also change the syntax for variable expansion. You should use `echo !Prev_FileName!` instead.